# Display alias instead of node

Tags: theming, 8

I am trying to create a link in page.html.twig that points to an alias. The code `{{ url('node/1') }}` shows an unexpected error, whereas {{ 'node/1' }} works fine but goes to url website/node/1.

In D7, one can use `<?php echo url('node/1'); ?>` and be directed to the page with proper alias.

What code can be used in D8 to display correct alias url?

Comment: Great question, hope you don't mind I re-phrased it a bit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `getAliasByPath` function to get the url alias for a path.

Put the below code in `THEME_NAME.theme` file.

```
function THEME_NAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $variables['url_alias'] = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getAliasByPath('/node/1');
}
```

Finally print the `url_alias` in your `page.html.twig` file.

```
{{ url_alias }}
```

Comment: I use {{ Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getAliasByPath('node/1') }} in page.tpl.twig show unexpected error

Comment: I have edited my answer, also add / before the path (/node/1).

Answer (score 1):

The twig functions `url` and `path` operate on *routes* and not *paths*, so you must specify the route name and the necessary parameters.

```
{{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'node': 1}) }}
```